# How can I get data attributes from rlang's .data like I can with .?

Tags: r, rlang

I am building a tidy-compatible function for use inside `dplyr`'s `mutate` where I'd like to pass a variable and also the data set I'm working with, and use information from both to build a vector.

As a basic example, imagine I want to return a string containing the mean of the variable and the number of rows in the data set (I know I could just take the length of `var`, ignore that, it's an example).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

info <- function(var,df = get(".",envir = parent.frame())) {
  paste(mean(var),nrow(df),sep=', ')
}

dat <- data.frame(a = 1:10, i = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)))

#Works fine, 'types' contains '5.5, 10'
dat %>% mutate(types = info(a))
```

Ok, great so far. But now maybe I want it to work with grouped data. `var` will be from just one group, but `.` would be the full data set. So instead I'll use `rlang`'s `.data` pronoun, which is just the data being worked with.

However, `.data` is not like `.`. `.` is the data set, but `.data` is just a pronoun from which I can pull variables with `.data[[varname]]`.

```
info2 <- function(var,df = get(".data",envir = parent.frame())) {
  paste(mean(var),nrow(.data),sep=', ')
}

#Doesn't work. nrow(.data) gives blank strings
dat %>% group_by(i) %>% mutate(types = info2(a))
```

How can I get the *full thing* from `.data`? I know I didn't include it in the example but specifically I both need some stuff from `attr(dat)` AND some stuff from the variables in `dat` that is properly subsetted for the grouping, so neither reverting to `.` nor just pulling out variables and getting stuff from there would work.

Comment: I don't think you can. As you say, `.data` is not really a data frame, it has its own class (`rlang_data_pronoun` without "parent" classes), and `rlang` doesn't want you to use it any other way. The class doesn't have methods defined for `dim` or `nrow`, and will actually throw an error if you use `[` or `length` on it.

Comment: Hmm, shoot, that's too bad. Maybe I can just have it pass both `.` and `.data`. It's clunky but would work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5793905/alexis) mentioned in the above comment, this is not possible, as it's not the intended use of `.data`. However, now that I've given up on doing this directly, I've worked up a kludge using a combination of `.` and `.data`.

```
info <- function(var,df = get(".",envir = parent.frame())) {
  #First, get any information you need from .
  fulldatasize <- nrow(df)

  #Then, check if you actually need .data,
  #i.e. the data is grouped and you need a subsample
  if (length(var) < nrow(df)) {
      #If you are, get the list of variables you want from .data, maybe all of them
      namesiwant <- names(df)

      #Get .data
      datapronoun <- get('.data',envir=parent.frame())

      #And remake df using just the subsample
      df <- data.frame(lapply(namesiwant, function(x) datapronoun[[x]]))
      names(df) <- namesiwant
  }

  #Now do whatever you want with the .data data
  groupsize <- nrow(df)

  paste(mean(var),groupsize,fulldatasize,sep=', ')
}

dat <- data.frame(a = 1:10, i = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)))

#types contains the within-group mean, then 5, then 10
dat %>% group_by(i) %>% mutate(types = info(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `length()` instead of `nrow()` here ?

```r
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:10, i = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)))

info <- function(var) {
  paste(mean(var),length(var),sep=', ')
}
dat %>% group_by(i) %>% mutate(types = info(a))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#> # Groups:   i [2]
#>        a     i types
#>    <int> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1     1     1 3, 5 
#>  2     2     1 3, 5 
#>  3     3     1 3, 5 
#>  4     4     1 3, 5 
#>  5     5     1 3, 5 
#>  6     6     2 8, 5 
#>  7     7     2 8, 5 
#>  8     8     2 8, 5 
#>  9     9     2 8, 5 
#> 10    10     2 8, 5
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I know I could do this, but that would just solve the specific example and not the general problem. There's information needed from the data set.

Comment: Could you give an example less trivial to solve by a way that doesn't suit you ? I suspect your real case might not need as much complexity as your own answer uses.

Comment: Specifically, I need three things to be passed in: (1) the group-subsetted var [done by var], (2) several other variables from the group-subsetted data set [done by .data], and (3) information about WHICH other variables I need in (2), which is stored in attr(., "varnames"). (3) is lost with .data, so it seems like I need to grab both .data for (2) and . for (3).